# MEF not loading DLL after adding metadata

Tags: c#, mef

After adding Metadata to my MEF exports one of my DLL will no longer load, whereas the other does.  I declared my variable like so:

```
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<IOOOContract, IOOOContractMetaData>> plugins;
```

and I defined my metadata interface:

```
    public interface IOOOContractMetaData {
        string name { get; }
    }
```

To load the code I just used what I think is the standard way:

```
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"...."));

        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
```

The plugin that I want to load is just a class library that is defined like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IOOOContract))]
[ExportMetadata("name", "TMRAT")]
public class Class1 : IOOOContract
```

If I run mefx.exe against the directory, I see each DLL properly listing the IOOOContract, and none of them show any output if I use the /rejected flag.  The only thing that I can think which might be effecting it is that the DLL which doesn't load has a reference to another DLL that's not part of the GAC.  I tried copying that DLL to the same directory listed on the DirectoryCatalog() but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried adding the .dll in the application base (where the executable is)? If this works, then you will either have to add this directory to the private probing path of the application.